# c# finding index of contextSubMenu item clicked

Tags: c#

So I have a basic layout here where I populate a submenu item of a contextMenu with preset items. I'm trying to find the 'index' of the selected submenuItem selected. What method is there for this? I found a method to find the index of the main menu items, but not the submenu items.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace rcMenu
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Product newProductA = new Product();
            newProductA.Name = "Ice Cream";
            newProductA.Category = "Dessert";
            newProductA.Price = "Free";
            productList.Add(newProductA);

            Product newProductB = new Product();
            newProductB.Name = "Cherries";
            newProductB.Category = "Produce";
            newProductB.Price = "$10.00";
            productList.Add(newProductB);

            Product newProductC = new Product();
            newProductC.Name = "Soda";
            newProductC.Category = "Beverage";
            newProductC.Price = "$1.99";
            productList.Add(newProductC);
        }

        public static List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();

        public class Product
        {
            public String Name { get; set; }
            public String Category { get; set; }
            public String Price { get; set; }
        }

        private void contextMenuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            //works only for main menu items
            int index = contextMenuStrip1.Items.IndexOf(e.ClickedItem)

            //need index of submenu ITEM CLICKED??
        }

        private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            (contextMenuStrip1.Items[0] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Clear();

            foreach (var p in productList)
            {
                var itemName = p.Name;
                (contextMenuStrip1.Items[0] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(itemName, null, SelectedPreset);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need the index itself? Or are you just using it to look up the Product?

Comment: Using it to look up a product from a List. So the 3rd item in the contextMenu preset list, would be the 3rd item in the variable stored List.

Comment: @DJKRAZE I looked into the post you are referencing prior to posting this and I saw he was using 'SubmenuItem_Click' which I couldn't find any information on when attempting to research his results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can do the following.**

```
    private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        (contextMenuStrip1.Items[0] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Clear();
        (contextMenuStrip1.Items[0] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItemClicked -= DropDownItemClicked;
        (contextMenuStrip1.Items[0] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItemClicked += DropDownItemClicked;


        foreach (var p in productList)
        {
            var itemName = p.Name;
           (contextMenuStrip1.Items[0] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(itemName, null, SelectedPreset);
            }
    }

    private void DropDownItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        var parent = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;

        int index = parent.DropDownItems.IndexOf(e.ClickedItem);
        Debug.WriteLine(index);
    }
```

**But even better to do this:**

```
    private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        (contextMenuStrip1.Items[0] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Clear();

        foreach (var p in productList)
        {
            var itemName = p.Name;
            var item = (contextMenuStrip1.Items[0] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add(itemName, null, SelectedPreset);
            item.Tag = p;
        }
    }


    private void SelectedPreset(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var menuItem = (ToolStripItem)sender;
        Debug.WriteLine(((Product)menuItem.Tag).Name);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
 public class Product
 {
   // :
   public override string ToString() { return Name; }
 }
```

then in the `contextMenuStrip1_Opening` store the whole object, not just the name.

```
   private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ddi = (contextMenuStrip1.Items[0] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems;
        ddi.Clear();

        foreach (var p in productList)
        {
            ddi.Add(p, null, SelectedPreset);
        }
    }
```

Comment: there is no submenuItem click event which can catch the senders or e.click index?